# Android App Glitch and Lag suddenly

Tags: android, gradle, lag, navigation-drawer, visual-glitch

I'm making a new android app, the first versions of it run fluidly after some build with gradle and improvement the app has start to Lag and Glitch. Those problem aren't caused by CPU or Memory OverUse.
Even if i try to remove entire libraryes or part of code it still glitch and lag and it doesen't return fluid like old releases ones.

To explain it better if I open a Lateral Drawer Nav Layout, it Lags and if i touch the scrollbar it becames blue. Also some animations and even transiction glitch.

I have developeda more complex and heavy app but nothing like this is happening on there.

The Lag example: https://youtu.be/6Xq47c7y0A0

Comment: How does the app look with overdraw turned on? https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/dev-options-overdraw.html

Comment: Did you solve the problem ? I experienced the same and I don't know where to look. Please provide some info.